# There's something like require once in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, rest, oop

I've made a class in Javascript, but I want that in my `constructor` be made a Ajax Request, and that the return go to my object attributes, but it's not working. Where I'm wrong?

```
class pergunta {
      constructor(perguntas = [], respostas = [], desafios = [], valor = 100, posicao = 0){
        this.perguntas = perguntas;
        this.respostas = respostas;
        this.desafios = desafios;
        this.posicao = posicao;
        this.valor = valor;
        jQuery.ajax({
           url: '../php/consulta.php' + location.search,
           type: "GET",
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(pergunta, desafio){
               this.perguntas = pergunta.pergunta;
               this.respostas = pergunta.resposta;
               this.desafios = desafio.descricao;

             }
           });

}

    }
    const perguntas = new pergunta();
    console.log(perguntas);
```

Comment: Check what `this` refers to inside your anonymous function.

Answer (score -1):

When you use jQuery's AJAX function, the value of `this` inside the callback is a reference to the request object. If you want to access the value of `this` from the parent scope, use `.bind`:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
       url: '../php/consulta.php' + location.search,
       type: "GET",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(pergunta, desafio){
           this.perguntas = pergunta.pergunta;
           this.respostas = pergunta.resposta;
           this.desafios = desafio.descricao;

         }.bind(this)
       });
```

If you need to support a browser that doesn't allow `.bind`, use an extra variable:

```
class pergunta {
      constructor(perguntas = [], respostas = [], desafios = [], valor = 100, posicao = 0){
        var _this = this;
        this.perguntas = perguntas;
        this.respostas = respostas;
        this.desafios = desafios;
        this.posicao = posicao;
        this.valor = valor;
        jQuery.ajax({
           url: '../php/consulta.php' + location.search,
           type: "GET",
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(pergunta, desafio){
               _this.perguntas = pergunta.pergunta;
               _this.respostas = pergunta.resposta;
               _this.desafios = desafio.descricao;

             }
           });

}
```